# Category Buttons

Tags: php, jquery, sql, html

I am trying to create a category button for my e-commerce website. Been trying to generate an idea of the button which clicked, so that the jQuery will be able to toggle the database which each represents. So far the idea is getting there but missing something.

So far all I have been doing is inputting the IDs statically and the outcome is grouping filter results, on top of each other instead of switching their results.

The database connection with SQL:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'firmciti');

if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Database connect failed with follwing errors: '. mysqli_connect_error();
    die();
}
error_reporting();


$sql = "SELECT * FROM nav";
$squery = $db->query($sql);
$pql = "SELECT * FROM companies";
$pquery = $db->query($pql);
$gql = "SELECT * FROM companies WHERE catId = 2";
$gquery = $db->query($gql);
$fql = "SELECT * FROM companies WHERE catId = 3";
$fquery = $db->query($fql);
$aql = "SELECT * FROM companies WHERE catId = 4";
$aquery = $db->query($aql);
$cql = "SELECT * FROM companies WHERE catId = 5";
$cquery = $db->query($cql);
...
?>
```

The jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#1").click(function(){
        $("#view").toggle();

    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#2").click(function(){
        $("#view1").toggle();

    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#3").click(function(){
        $("#view2").toggle();

    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#4").click(function(){
        $("#view3").toggle();

    });
...</script>
```

The html:

```
<?php while($cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($squery)): ?> 
<button id="<?=$cat['catId']; ?>"><img src="<?=$cat['img'];?>" style="height: 80px; width: 80px; margin: 0 15px;"/> </button>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<!--all-->

<div id="view" style="margin: 0 20px" >

<?php while($comp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pquery)): ?> 
<!-- Gallery list-->
    <button class="w3-button w3-white w3-border w3-hover-amber " href="" type="button" style="width: 340px; height: 100px; margin: 5px;"><div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="<?=$comp['compLogo'];?>" style="height: 80px; width: 80px";/>
            </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <h4 class="w3-display-topleft"><?=$comp['compName'];?></h4><br><br>


            <h6 class="w3-half">25min</h6>

        </div>
    </button>

<?php endwhile;?>
</div>


<!--grocery-->
<div id="view1" style="margin: 0 20px" hidden="">

<?php while($comp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($gquery)): ?> 
<!-- Gallery list-->
    <button class="w3-button w3-white w3-border w3-hover-amber " href="" type="button" style="width: 340px; height: 100px; margin: 5px;"><div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="<?=$comp['compLogo'];?>" style="height: 80px; width: 80px";/>
            </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <h4 class="w3-display-topleft"><?=$comp['compName'];?></h4><br><br>


            <h6 class="w3-half">25min</h6>

        </div>
    </button>

<?php endwhile;?>
</div>

<!--food-->
<div id="view2" style="margin: 0 20px" hidden="">

<?php while($comp = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fquery)): ?> 
<!-- Gallery list-->
    <button class="w3-button w3-white w3-border w3-hover-amber " href="" type="button" style="width: 340px; height: 100px; margin: 5px;"><div class="col-xs-4">
        <img src="<?=$comp['compLogo'];?>" style="height: 80px; width: 80px";/>
            </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <h4 class="w3-display-topleft"><?=$comp['compName'];?></h4><br><br>


            <h6 class="w3-half">25min</h6>

        </div>
    </button>

<?php endwhile;?>
</div>
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]. If your question is only about jQuery, please remove all PHP. If you want to connect to the server each time you toggle, please first look into PHP/AJAX

Comment: Why you are doing that ? You are doing multiple queries and save them on load of your document and then showing them in your page. Look, just use Ajax with it, and in your PHP set a condition that is sended by Ajax, if value sent from Ajax is 1 per example, execute query number 1 and return the result into a div by removing the old data and replace by the new one and so on.

Comment: ok thanks, I just started coding since february so not really adept with the languages

Comment: Ajax is part of jQuery. The Ajax script is so easy, by using my method, you will reduce alots of your html, php and JS codes. Try Ajax and  if there some errors, re-edit this post and I am ready for help